# Why does v-progress-circular (v2.5.0+) no longer display

Tags: vuetify.js

Since vuetify@2.5.0 the v-progress-circular—visible class is not applied on any progress components - meaning that just a dot is being displayed.

Is there anything I need to change from my existing pre 2.5.0 codebase to make it work?

My html code works on versions pre 2.5.0 ...

```
<v-progress-circular indeterminate color="muted"></v-progress-circular>
```

If I inspect the code, vuetify generates the following:

```
<div data-v-7ba5bd90="" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="v-progress-circular v-progress-circular--indeterminate muted--text" style="height: 32px; width: 32px;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="22.857142857142858 22.857142857142858 45.714285714285715 45.714285714285715" style="transform: rotate(0deg);">
    <circle fill="transparent" cx="45.714285714285715" cy="45.714285714285715" r="20" stroke-width="5.714285714285714" stroke-dasharray="125.664" stroke-dashoffset="125.66370614359172px" class="v-progress-circular__overlay"></circle>
  </svg>
  <div class="v-progress-circular__info"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the classlist for the wrapping div *should* also contain

```
v-progress-circular--visible
```

But it doesn't. When I add that manually in the devtools the circular progress components spins in the expected way. Without it, it just renders as a dot.

In vuetify versions pre 2.5.0 it adds the v-progress-circular--visible class fine.

Has a bug crept in when upgrading to 2.5.0 - on the documentation site I can see the spinners spinning fine ...

Comment: Possibly some other problems occurred during the migration. It works fine in official docs and at some sandboxes. There are also no such opened issues at vuetify github. Could you reproduce your error at CodePen sandbox?

Comment: Yes it must have occurred during migration. When I inserted a debugger statement in the vuetify directives/intersect file to see what's going on, the problem magically disappeared. Perhaps it was some sort of webpacker caching thing going on?

Answer (score 0):

It must have occurred during migration between the different versions.

When I inserted a debugger statement in the vuetify directives/intersect file

[https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/0eec92f0/packages/vuetify/src/directives/intersect/index.ts#L3](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/0eec92f0/packages/vuetify/src/directives/intersect/index.ts#L30)0

to see what's going on, the problem magically disappeared. Perhaps it was some sort of webpacker caching thing going on?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix, you can simply manually add the `v-progress-circular--visible` class on the component. From my side work fine. Can be a workarround until this was fixed by Vuetify team.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify()
});
```

```html
<!-- Comment this one... -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.5/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- ...and uncomment this one to see before 2.5 there is no bug -->
<!-- <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.4/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <h1>Bugged one since 2.5+</h1>
      <v-progress-circular
        indeterminate
        color="red"
      ></v-progress-circular>

      <h1>Workaround issue for 2.5+</h1>
      <v-progress-circular
        indeterminate
        class="v-progress-circular--visible"
        color="green"
      ></v-progress-circular>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.3.5/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Release 2.5 (Avalon) included a patch [13136](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/pull/13136) to implement a feature request [12731](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/12731) to make the progress components use less CPU. This patch uses the `intersect` directive to have animations play by adding the `v-progress-linear--visible` only if the progress component is visible.

It looks like the `intersect` directive fires to turn off the visibility when the page loads but doesn't always fire to turn it back on so there is no animation.

There are two workarounds:

- Add the appropriate class, either `v-progress-circular--visible` or `v-progress-linear--visible` to every component that uses a progress bar (progress bars, tables, autocompletes, etc.)
- Add some CSS to force `animation-play-state` to `running` for the appropriate role:

```
    [role='progressbar'] {
      & .long,
      & .short {
        animation-play-state: running !important;
      }
    }
```